# JQuery dynamic checkbox to hide dynamic slider not working

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I have a form which has a slider and a checkbox, and based on the checkbox being checked or unchecked, I need to hide a slider.  Both these elements are created by JQuery inside a dialog box.

My two lines of code for the dynamic inputs is:

```
$('#msgBox').html($('#msgBox').html() + '<div class="table-row"><div class="table-col-l">Number:</div><div class="table-col-r"><input id="lunchtbc" type="checkbox"> TBC</div></div></div>')
$('#msgBox').html($('#msgBox').html() + '<div class="table-row" id="lunchnumber"><div class="table-col-l">Number:</div><div class="table-col-r"><div id="lunchnum"></div><span id="lunchno"></span></div></div></div>')
```

And further down below this code:

```
$('#lunchtbc').on('click',function() {
    $('#lunchnumber').hide()
});
```

I'm not sure why this just doesn't want to work (I've also tried it with a radio button set with the same results).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [delegating](http://api.jquery.com/on/) it. So in your case it could be:

```
$('body').on('click', '#lunchtbc', function(){
    $('#lunchnumber').hide()
});
```

The reason this will work is because you probably try to bind the click at a moment the checkbox doesn't exist. So by delegating it, it will also work on dynamically added elements.

I tested it on a [JSfiddle (here)](http://jsfiddle.net/veritas87/323wxnk6/) and it works.

Comment: There's my learn-something-new-every-day moment!  Many thanks, I understand now that although I've added the code in after the code, when the code executes it doesn't actually exist!